# Segues will not run on IOS 4 now what?

Tags: ios

I have a project on Xcode and I am pretty beginner so I started designing my code of course using segues and now I realized that this project will only work on IOS 5!

I guess I will give up before I even started! What am I gonna do now? Is there anything I can transform my project to IOS 4? I am so disappointed and wish I didn't have to design for IOS.

Comment: Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the concept of segues was introduced first in iOS5, however it is also stated in the library documentation.

Nevertheless, you can try to create standalone nib files and copy your UI*ViewControls from the storyboard into the nib file(s). Of course you are still not allowed to use segues but you can easily reintroduce IBActions to handle transitions between the views. It's still some effort to migrate, but not an impossible mission.

In order to avoid such a situation, I would suggest you to make a short requirement analysis (functional as well as non functional) before coding.

Comment: "....make a short requirement analysis before coding." That's right I would love to do that but the project just came to me with snapshot pictures and no information. I have no experience on ios that's another issue. Couldn't do any research because of time pressure. Starting to code without no prior knowledge not good thanks to my employer.

Thanks for the advise much appreciated I will try that out.